# Combine certain values in one array with values in another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would like to combine the values which contain the prefix `lt_` in `$url`  with the values in `$color` and create a new array `$new`. Both arrays `$url` and `$color` store values for the next 36 hours:

```
print_r($url);
```

outputs

```
 Array(
     [0]  => "http://example.com/color/green.png",
     [1]  => "http://example.com/color/lt_green.png",
     [2]  => "http://example.com/color/lt_blue.png",
     [3]  => "http://example.com/color/blue.png",
     [4]  => "http://example.com/color/blue.png",
     [5]  => "http://example.com/color/yellow.png",
     ..
     [35] => "http://example.com/color/lt_blue.png",
     );
```

and

```
print_r($color);
```

outputs

```
Array(
     [0]  => "Green",
     [1]  => "Green",
     [2]  => "Blue",
     [3]  => "Blue",
     [4]  => "Blue",
     [5]  => "Yellow",
     ...
     [35] => "Blue",
     );
```

I have managed to find the string part `lt_` in `$url` and get the keys in `$new` but how can I add "Light" (or `lt_`) to the corresponding values in `$color` to populate `$new`?

```
$new = array(
     [0]  => "Green",
     [1]  => "Light Green",
     [2]  => "Light Blue",
     [3]  => "Blue",
     [4]  => "Blue",
     [5]  => "Yellow",
     ...
     [35] => "Light Blue",
 );
```

I have managed to create an array with only the keys which values contain `lt_`:

```
$lt = 'lt_';
foreach($url as $key1=>$value1)
{
  foreach($color as $key2=>$value2)
  {
      if (strpos($value1,$lt) !== false)
      {
          $new[$key1] = array();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: do both arrays have the same size? Do the indexes of both arrays correspond to each other?

Comment: @acontell Yes, both arrays are the same size and the indexes correspond to one another.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've added an answer, hope it helps

Comment: @acontell Thanks! I have to run an errand, I'll be back in a while and try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both arrays have the same size and the indexes correspond, you can iterate and add to the new array the color with the prefix or without it depending on the condition:

```
$arr = Array("http://example.com/color/green.png",
    "http://example.com/color/lt_green.png",
    "http://example.com/color/lt_blue.png",
    "http://example.com/color/blue.png",
    "http://example.com/color/blue.png",
    "http://example.com/color/yellow.png",);

$arr2 = Array(
    "Green",
    "Green",
    "Blue",
    "Blue",
    "Blue",
    "Yellow",);

$new = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr2); $i += 1) {
    (strpos($arr[$i], 'lt_') !== false) ?
                    $new[] = "Light " . $arr2[$i] :
                    $new[] = $arr2[$i];
}
print_r($new);
```

Comment: That's a great answer and it does exactly what I needed. Thank you!